# Qt-Creator freezes my Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, qt-creator

I am trying to develop apps for Ubuntu mobile, but whenever I try to run the app in an emulator everything freezes and then I have to restart my system.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Qt Creator 3.1.1 based on Qt 5.2.1 (GCC 4.8.2, 64 bit).

I am facing this problem. After few minutes of Qt usage, suddenly the behavior of Ubuntu becomes sluggish. Once Qt is closed, it's back to normal.

Results of `ubuntu-drivers devices`

```
driver: intel-microcode - distro non-free
```

Results of `lspci -nn | grep VGA`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5916] (rev 02).
```

On my Dell laptop, I do have an AMD Radeon graphics card, but in Ubuntu it's not used to my knowledge. Kindly assist on how to resolve this hanging Qt behavior.

Comment: From the terminal run `ubuntu-drivers devices` to check if you are missing a graphics processor driver. You can edit your question and add the results of `ubuntu-drivers devices` or else post it in a comment. Also post the results of the command `lspci -nn | grep VGA`.

Comment: @karel, I am facing this problem. After few minutes of Qt usage, suddenly the behaviour of Ubuntu becomes sluggish. Once Qt is closed, it's back to normal. For above commands, I get following output: `driver: intel-microcode - distro non-free` and `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5916] (rev 02)`. On my dell laptop, I do have "AMD RADEON GRAPHICS" card, but in Ubuntu it's not used in my knowledge. Kindly assist on how to resolve this hanging Qt behaviour?